# Assign value after ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do a table with ng-repeat. This is my code

```
          <table class="tab2" >
              <thead> 
                <tr>
                  <th>Currency: USD '000s</th>
                  <th ng-repeat="s in periodosCF">{{s.periodo | date:"yyyy"}}</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="n in nombreFilasCF" class="{{n.fondo}}">
                <td  style="width: 32%;"><div  class="bordeTab">
                  <div  class="{{n.color}}First" >
                     {{n.nombre}} 
                   </div> <br>
                  </div>
                </td>

                <td ng-repeat="dato in datosCF" ng-if="n.nombre == dato.nombre">
                  <div class="{{n.color}}" >
                    {{dato.valor}}
                  </div><br> 
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Once it enter to this ng-repeat="dato in datosCF", I do and if to print a value, but if the if returns me false I need to print this "-".

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please give us a sample value for `datosCF` and an example of what HTML you would like it to produce.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to include all rows, but the content of the row is different based on some condition. If that's the case, you can try moving the conditional logic into the body of your `<td>` element, and having two divs with contradictory `ng-if` expressions:

```
      <table class="tab2" >
          <thead> 
            <tr>
              <th>Currency: USD '000s</th>
              <th ng-repeat="s in periodosCF">{{s.periodo | date:"yyyy"}}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="n in nombreFilasCF" ng-class="n.fondo">
            <td  style="width: 32%;"><div  class="bordeTab">
              <div  ng-class="n.color + 'First'">
                 {{n.nombre}} 
               </div> <br>
              </div>
            </td>

            <td ng-repeat="dato in datosCF">
              <div ng-if="n.nombre === dato.nombre" ng-class="n.color">
                {{dato.valor}}
              </div>
              <div ng-if="n.nombre !== dato.nombre">
                -
              </div><br> 
            </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I also changed your interpolated `class` attributes to `ng-class`.